# I forget it Jsecure admin url, how can I get it back?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, backend, custom-backend

If somebody knows Jsecure component, can tell is very good extension for hide the Joom back-end url... But I forget it what type of word I was give to Jsecure for access to my back-end.

I find few sulotion on the Internet, how can I see it what is that key what I lost it... Might be all sulotion is only for Joomla 1.5, but I using Joomla 2.5. So I have find the Jsecure rows in the prefix_extensions table and I open it. I think I have a good luck, but when I seen the "Params" are is fully empty. Nowhere I can see this admin url key... Can somebody help me please how I can get it back my admin?

Comment: have you checked the database?

Comment: Yes of corse! But I really can't find where was saved the key...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSecure doesn't save the the key in the database.

The easiest way is to use phpMyAdmin (or it's equivalent on your host) and disable the extension.

In phpMyAdmin, find your JSecure row in `#__extensions` and change the value of the `enabled` column to `0`, this will disable the extension, you can then go back into the `Extension Manager` re-enable JSecure and setup a new secret word.

*By the way if you already use Akeeba AdminTools — this functionality (the secret word for `/adminsitrator` access) is built into the WAF settings.*

These are the instructions for manual deletion that are included with JSecure:

> #### Following are steps to remove the jSecure 2.1.10 manually Joomla 2.5:
>
> Delete the component and plug-in entry from database.
>
> ```
> jos_jsecurelog
> jos_assets
> com_jsecure - jsecure
> jos_extensions
> System - jsecure - plugin
> jsecure - component
> jos_menu
> COM_JSECURE_AUTHENTICATION
> BASIC_CONFIGURATION
> ADVANCED_CONFIGURATION
> VIEW_LOG
> HELP
> ```
>
> Delete the below mentioned folders & files.
>
> ```
> \administrator\components\com_jsecure
> \administrator\language\en-GB
> en-GB.com_jsecure.ini,
> en-GB.com_jsecure.sys.ini,
> en-GB.plg_system_jsecure.ini
> \components\com_jsecure
> \plugins\system\jsecure
> ```

Comment: Hi! Thanks your help! It looks like very good, but not working... I dasabled all Jsecure plugin, component but can't access to my admin panel... Have you any another suloliton for fix it?

Comment: Thanks! My "Answer" is fixed my issue, but thanks again your help!

Answer (score 2):

With ftp manager (filezla or other) go : plugins => system => look "jsecure.php" and rename the file to "jsecureshit.php" (or other), Next time try to access your site and : it works !
that's all folks !

Comment: The best solution! Especially for new developers

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer for my question. I hope this helps everyone who using this component. Do not delete manually Jsecure files, because after you will never can use again this component. Just uninstall with Joomla Extension Manager!

Thanks for cppl to find the solution!

So the first, the problem is: How to get back the Joomla 2.5 admin if you have forget it you key. Open your MySQL and find your-prefix_extensions table. Find the "System - jsecure" colum and open it for edit. Change 1 in "enabled" and "access" to 0. Clean your Joomla cache, or wait when is automatic cleaned. After that you can access to your admin area. If maybe not, find the "jsecure" colum as well and open it to edit. Change 1 in "enabled" to 0. But when you sing-in to your admin area, after change back to 1 because you will never see that component in the admin page. So that is the solution to get back your admin area.

But! I think the Jsecure 3.0 have a bug, because if I change the key and enabled the component again you will can't access to your admin area. I will send this bug, but is better to upgrade to 3.0.1. Important is, you can get back your admin and can uninstall that component better like manually.

Answer (score 0):

add 2 more files into it. if you have applied key for it then in administrator folder delete .htaccess and .htpasswd